# Create maven repository on server

Tags: maven, tomcat, artifactory

I created maven repository as described [here](http://www.theserverside.com/news/1364121/Setting-Up-a-Maven-Repository), but I need to set up maven repository on our companie's server. I am stuck at step 7 of the tutorial. I do not have a .m2 folder on server. Where do I create this server? Do I have to make maven project for the directory to appear?

P.S. It is my first day with maven, so be gentle. Any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: Step 7 talks about settings on local machines

Comment: I know. So what about remote machine?

Answer (score 0):

Artifactory come with all the setup you need to use it as Maven repository.
You just install it, run it, and you're done. Take a look at [one minute setup](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XExvsdSITsY) screencast.